# Joining tables but displaying all the values of a look up table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a look up table, basically with credit card types

```
ID |  CCType         |
-----------------------
1  | AMEX            |
2  | VISA            |
3  | MASTER CARD     |
4  | OTHER           |
```

Then I have another table with transactions where CCTypeID is the ID in the look up table

```
TransID   |  CCTypeID   | TransactionName | OrderID |
-----------------------------------------------------
1         | 2           | BILLPAY         |10
2         | 4           | SECUREPAYMENT   |13
3         | 1           | BILLPAY         |15
```

Then finally I have another table with the orders

```
    OrderId | OrderDate   | Product   |   TransID  |
    ------------------------------------------------
    10      |  2012-02-27 |Grapes     | 1
    13      |  2012-02-26 |Wine       | 2
    14      |  2012-01-26 |Pepper     | 6
    15      |  2012-01-26 |Apple      | 1

I want to create a view that looks like this

OrderDate  | CCType      |  Processed
----------- ---------------------------
2012-02-27 | AMEX        |   0
2012-02-27 | VISA        |   1
2012-02-27 | MASTER CARD |   0
2012-02-27 | OTHER       |   0
2012-02-26 | AMEX        |   0
2012-02-26 | VISA        |   0
2012-02-26 | MASTER CARD |   0
2012-02-26 | OTHER       |   1
```

I have tried to RIGHT OUTER JOIN the credit card types with the transactions on the CCTypeID and ID respectively, then a INNER JOIN with orders on ORDERID, grouped by ORDER.DATE and CardType but it only shows whereever there are values, is there a way to make it so that it still lists the credit card types no matter if there are transactions or orders for the date? just show zero for that card type?.

Will truly appreciate the help.

Comment: where are you pulling the Processed field from?  It does not appear in any of the tables you have shown

Comment: @bluefeet - It seems to be a count of records for that date and card type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic query should be something like this...

```
SELECT
  Orders.OrderDate,
  CardType.CCType,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  Orders
LEFT JOIN
  Transactions
    ON  Transactions.TransID = Orders.TransID
    AND Transactions.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
LEFT JOIN
  CardType
    ON CardType.ID = Transaction.CCTypeID
GROUP BY
  Orders.OrderDate,
  CardType.CCType
```

If you need "All Dates" to have values, then you need an extra table to join on.  For example, make a table called `calendar` and pre-populate it with all the dates you'll ever need, then create an index on the date field.  Then you can re-order your query to force every combination that you want a record for...

```
SELECT
  Calendar.Date,
  CardType.CCType,
  COUNT(Transaction.CCTypeID)
FROM
  Calendar
CROSS JOIN
  CardType
LEFT JOIN
  (
    Transactions
  INNER JOIN
    Orders
      ON  Transactions.TransID = Orders.TransID
      AND Transactions.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
  )
    ON  CardType.ID   = Transactions.CCTypeID
    AND Calendar.Date = Orders.OrderDate
WHERE
  Calendar.Date BETWEEN ??? AND ???
GROUP BY
  Calendar.Date,
  CardType.CCType
```

Answer (score 1):

I am really only adding to the existing answer here, as the second part of the answer is right, but the first part does not cross join as required so omits the scenario where the OP may require all card types on all dates that had orders. I am not sure of the proper etiquette for this as I still want to take advantage of the code formatting that comes with an answer...

```
-- CREATE SAMPLE DATA
CREATE TABLE #CCType (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, CCType VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL)
INSERT #CCType VALUES (1, 'AMEX'), (2, 'VISA'), (3, 'MASTER CARD'), (4, 'OTHER')
CREATE TABLE #Trans (TransID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, CCTypeID INT NOT NULL, Transactionname VARCHAR(15), OrderID INT NOT NULL)
INSERT #Trans VALUES (1, 2, 'BIILPAY', 10), (2, 4, 'SECUREPAYMENT', 13), (3, 1, 'BIILPAY', 15)
CREATE TABLE #Orders (OrderID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, OrderDate DATETIME NOT NULL, Product VARCHAR(10), TransID INT)
INSERT #Orders VALUES (10, '20120227', 'Grapes', 1), (13, '20120226', 'Wine', 2), (14, '20120226', 'Pepper', 6), (15, '20120226', 'Apples', 1)
-- END CREATE SAMPLE DATA

SELECT  OrderDate, 
        CCType, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ID = CCTypeID THEN 1 END) [Processed]
FROM    #CCType, #Orders, #trans
WHERE   #Orders.TransID = #Trans.TransID
AND     #Orders.OrderID = #Trans.OrderID
GROUP BY OrderDate, CCType, ID
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC, ID

-- DISPOSE OF SAMPLE DATA
DROP TABLE #Orders, #CCType, #Trans
```

Comment: Not sure that you want `ID` in the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @Dems It is only so I can include it in the `ORDER BY` Since the cards appear in ID order in the example in the question.